# appcompat-v7: Android HelloWorld App Error

Tags: android, android-studio

i just installed AndroidStudio on a MacBook Pro. At first i had i couple of problems with the SDKs but it seems fine right now. However when i create a blank Application via `new Project...` it seems to have a couple of errors.

When i try to compile i get the following message:

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':EBVDemo'.
>   Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':EBVDemo:_DebugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
>           Required by:
>               EBVDemoProject:EBVDemo:unspecified

After the first compile attempt the MainActivity was also marked with an error, saying it couldn't resolve ActionBarActivity.

I have an installation on a linux machine without these problems. Could anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the "Android Support Repository" trough the "Android SDK Manager"?

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Can you post it as answer? Any idea why although the app compiles fine the editor still complains not being able to resolve ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Maybe you have to sync AndroidStudio with your build.grade? Restart AndroidStudio or use the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in the toolbar.

Comment: It was just a restart. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone inform google about this? It's kind of embarassing to show an "unknown error" in the Hello World.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably have `appcompat-v7` declared as gradle dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

If so, make sure you have installed the "Android Support Repository" trough the "Android SDK Manager".